# Elements in CSS / HTML are not visible

Tags: html, css

It seems 3 items are not show on the generated page, am I mistyped anything ?

PHP:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');   
echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";


echo "  <title>This is a test</title>";
echo '    <link rel="stylesheet" href="t3.css">';
echo "</head>";

echo '<body>';
echo '<div class="f1">';
echo "testing...";
echo "</div>";

echo '<div class="f2">';
echo '<p class="f2 s1">first</p>';
echo '<p class="f2 s2">second</p>';
echo '<p class="f2 s3">third</p>';
echo '<form>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Press this button">';
echo '</form>';

echo '</div>';
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

CSS:

```
body 
{
   font-family: Arial;
   margin: 0px;
}


.f1 {
    float: left;
    height: 45px;    
    width: 100%;
    position:relative; 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: 100;
text-align: center;
font-size: 2.3em;
}
.f2 {
    float: left;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 10%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

  overflow: hidden;

}
.f2 .s1 {
   position: relative;
   left: 30px;
   top: 20px;
    color: red;
}

.f2 .s2 {
   position: relative;
   left: 30px;
   top: 50px;
    color: blue;
}

.f2 .s3 {
   position: relative;
   left: 30px;
   top: 70px;
    color: black;
}

.f2 input[type="submit"] {
    border-color: aqua;
}
```

My qestions are:

1. Why "second" and "third" element is not shown ?
2. Why the button (f2 input) is not show ?
3. Why I get this additional line in the middle rounded box ? http://imgur.com/5aDG3O9 - marked with orange. How can remove this ?

Thank you for you help !

Comment: because you are using position relative

Comment: Get rid of 1000 echos

Comment: devpro: isnt relative means (in this case) that relative from the top/left corner of this box I had created with f2 css class? If not, how can I make sure that I am positioning s1, s2, and s3 elements inside the f2 definied box ?

Comment: These elements ARE SHOWN, indeed, but they are all hidden behind other elements. @bub is right: take these "echos" out. You don't need to use this. You may have HTML elements in a PHP file. This question is wrongly flagged as PHP. You are just using PHP to display things, when the same could be done with pure HTML.

Comment: Ed de Almeida: ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use multiple `echo` here:

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="t3.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="f1">testing...</div>

<div class="f2">
    <p class="s1">first</p>
    <p class="s2">second</p>
    <p class="s3">third</p>
    <form>
    <input type="submit" value="Press this button">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**What you need?**

- No need to use `f2` class with your `<p>`, i am removing this
- No need to use `position:relative` with `s1,s2,s3` class.

**CSS:**

```
.s1 {left: 30px;top: 20px;color: red;}
.s2 {left: 30px;top: 50px; color: blue;}
.s3 {left: 30px;top: 70px; color: black;}
```

```css
 body 
{
   font-family: Arial;
   margin: 0px;
}


.f1 {
    float: left;
    height: 45px;    
    width: 100%;
    position:relative; 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: 100;
text-align: center;
font-size: 2.3em;
}
.f2 {
  float: left;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 10%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

  overflow: hidden;

}
.f2 .s1 {
   left: 30px;
   top: 20px;
   color: red;
}

.f2 .s2 {
   left: 30px;
   top: 50px;
   color: blue;
}

.f2 .s3 {
   left: 30px;
   top: 70px;
   color: black;
}

.f2 input[type="submit"] {
    border-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="t3.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="f1">testing...</div>

<div class="f2">
 <p class="s1">first</p>
 <p class="s2">second</p>
 <p class="s3">third</p>
 <form>
 <input type="submit" value="Press this button">
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```